# Adding item to list in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, libstdc++

I am using two classes in my C++ application. The code is as follows:

```
class MyMessageBox
{
public:
    void sendMessage(Message *msg, User *recvr);
    Message receiveMessage();
    list<Message> dataMessageList;
};

class User
{
public:
    MyMessageBox *dataMsgBox;
};
```

The msg is a pointer to a derived class object of Message class. I have implemented the function sendMessage as follows:

```
void MyMessageBox::sendMessage(Message *msg, User *recvr)
{
    Message &msgRef = *msg;
    recvr->dataMsgBox->dataMessageList.push_back(msgRef);
}
```

When I compile this code, I get the following error:
undefined reference to `vtable for Message'. Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: I am using GCC compiler gcc 4

Comment: What is the implementation of the Message class? Also, since you're using a std::list<Message>, your derived Message objects will be sliced to plain Message objects once you push_back them on the list. Use a list<Message*> instead.

Comment: For us to help you, you will need to add all the content of the file. There shouldn't be an error with what you just show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do with that msgRef, but it's wrong. Are you an ex-Java programmer, by any chance?

If `Message` is a base class for derivatives of `Message`, you need to store pointers in the list. Change `list<Message>` to `list<Message*>`; and `push_back(msgRef)` should become `push_back(msg)`, removing the `msgRef` code entirely.

Also, as a matter of style, it's a bad idea to chain lots of `->` operators together. It's better to implement a method on `User` in this case that adds a `Message` to its own list and call that.

Comment: Thanks Kylotan. I changed my code like you said, and it compiles fine now.

Comment: @Rakesh K - don't forget that you need extra cleanup code for the list if you have a list<Message \*>. The list destructor will _not_ delete the elements pointed to by the pointer. You have to delete them manually yourself or (recommended) use something like boost::shared_ptr<> to handle them as value objects that get destroyed when the last reference to them is destroyed. If you don't use either shared_ptr or clean up the list yourself, you will end up with a resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if you want to store a polymorphic object in a standard C++ container, you should store a pointer to the object and not an object of the base class. If you don't, you run into object slicing issues. Also, do yourself a favour and wrap the pointer in a smart pointer to prevent resource leaks - I would recommend boost::shared_ptr<>.

Given that you haven't shown us the code for Message, we can but guess what the problem is. As it's referring to a vtable, chances are that:

- You didn't declare any of Message's class members as `virtual`. Starting with the destructor would be a good idea
- You forgot to link against an object file that contains the compiled code for Message

By the way, creating the additional reference in `sendMessage()` is not necessary and IMHO doesn't exactly help readability. Just dereference the msg pointer in your call to push_back().

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a slightly contrived error message suggesting that you've not implemented a constructor for your message class. Have a look [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/161894-undefined-reference-vtable) and [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-referen)...

Given that you're trying to pass a pointer to a list of objects, the compiler is probably complaining that it has no way to convert `Message*` to `Message`. Try changing your list to a list of `Message*` as Kylotan suggests.

Is it a compile or a link error?

Comment: Not in this case. There is no good reason for implementing a *virtual* constructor in here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle subclassed Messages, you need to use a list of Message pointers rather than Message objects, and manage their lifetime. For convenience, I'd suggest making it

```
list< boost::shared_ptr<Message> > datamessageList
```

using the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) library. (And not to offend, but you do need to read up a bit more on C++ and pointers: it looks like you tried various permutations of your code until you got something that compiled...)

Answer (score 0):

As some are proposing better solutions: check out std::queue or std::deque to queue your messages.  So now you have:

```
std::queue<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Message> > dataMessageQueue;
```