# Should the order of linked libraries make a difference in compilation?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linker order - GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)
>   [GCC C++ Linker errors: Undefined reference to 'vtable for XXX', Undefined reference to 'ClassName::ClassName()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-refere)

I am using GCC to build an application. The main program calls a function (say, `myfunc()`)that resides in a static library (say, `libmylib.a`). This function calls the `cosf()` and `sinf()` function from math library.

Now, in gcc command line, I give the `-lmylib -lm` options, and the build goes fine. However, when the order of the libraries is changed, then the build fails with the error:

```
libmylib.a(mylib.o): In function `myfunc':
mylib.c:22: undefined reference to `cosf'
mylib.c:23: undefined reference to `sinf'
```

Why doesn't gcc complete the build with the libraries given in some order?

Comment: That is just the way it is. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363398/g-linking-order-dependency-when-linking-c-code-to-c-code

Comment: Strange that I did not see the linked questions  - but given these, I agree that this question is a dup.