# C++ linking object's files (G++)

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking

**class.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class CIntegerType {
 public:
    void Show ( void );

 private:
    T m_Data;
};
```

**class.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"

template <typename T>
void CIntegerType<T> :: Show ( void ) {
    cout << m_Data << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"

int main ( void ) {
    CIntegerType<uint32_t> UINT32;

    UINT32 . Show ();

    return 0;
}
```

This commands return:

g++ -Wall -pedantic -c main.cpp

g++ -Wall -pedantic -c class.cpp

g++ -Wall -pedantic -o class.o main.o

main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to 'CIntegerType< unsigned int>::Show()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: g++ -Wall -pedantic **-o class.o** main.o -- Looks like you're missing an argument

Comment: You might need to switch the objects around, My memory fails me but I think you must always specify your main loop object first when compiling.

Comment: Try putting the template function in the header.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your template implementation in the header file.

See: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try `g++ -Wall -pedantic -o main.o class.o` instead. You are facing the same problem as in this question: [g++ linking order dependency when linking c code to c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363398/g-linking-order-dependency-when-linking-c-code-to-c-code)

The linker searches for functions in the order they appear. Since you have a template function, its use in `main` must be fed to the linker prior to the actual code to instantiate it in `class`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it.

Output:
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 12

...

: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I tried both variant "g++ -Wall -pedantic -o main.o class.o" and "g++ -Wall -pedantic -o class.o main.o", but no result.