# How to include/link boost::regex library?

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-regex

I am trying to use the boost regex library but I can't manage to compile my program. All related questions which involve similar error messages seem to relate to situations where regex library wasn't properly linked. I think that I am linking it, but maybe I am doing something stupid... Perhaps someone sees my mistake?
Here is my test program:

```
// ~/workspace/test/test.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
int main(){
   std::string s("abaab");
   boost::regex r("[ab]*");
   std::cout << boost::regex_match(s,r) << std::endl;   
}
```

Here are the boost binaries (I installed them via `synaptic` on Xubuntu):

```
  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ls libboost_regex* -al
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2169582 Okt 13 05:14 libboost_regex.a
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Okt 13 05:13 libboost_regex.so -> libboost_regex.so.1.53.0
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1002568 Okt 13 05:14 libboost_regex.so.1.53.0
```

Nevertheless I'm getting quite an ugly error message when running

```
~/workspace/test$ g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -lboost_regex test.cpp
```

Here is the complete message:

```
  ~/workspace/test$ g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -lboost_regex test.cpp 
  /tmp/cc1yDf0v.o: In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
  test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE[_ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE]+0x4c): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
  /tmp/cc1yDf0v.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
  test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
  /tmp/cc1yDf0v.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>)':
  test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC2ES6_S6_RNS_13match_resultsIS6_S9_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsES6_[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC5ES6_S6_RNS_13match_resultsIS6_S9_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsES6_]+0xcd): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The header seems to be found, right? How else could gcc know about `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher` or `boost::basic_regex`?
I have no clue what the problem might be. Maybe it is the linking after all?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have installed the libboost-all-dev by using `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, try to compile it without `-L` option.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but compiling with `g++ -lboost_regex test.cpp` doesn't change anything -- same errors. However, this shows that my `-L` option doesn't succeed I guess.

Comment: Drop the trailing slash on your -L path.

Comment: I think, I should mention that it does compile with `g++ test.cpp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a`. But why doesn't the original command work?

Comment: Can there be some problem with gcc automatically selecting the `.so` instead of the `.a`? Or is this nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to make sure the library comes after your own sources.

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ test.cpp -lboost_regex
```

This is a FAQ:

- [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc/409470#409470)
- [g++ linking order dependency when linking c code to c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363398/g-linking-order-dependency-when-linking-c-code-to-c-code)

And probably quite a few more. I guess it's (sadly) one of those *rites-of-passage* that goes with the territory :(

Comment: You are right! Thanks! Who would have thought that this was the reason?! :)