# How to enable HDF5 in Armadillo using RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I'm using Armadillo via RcppArmadillo and would like to save matrices in the HDF5 format. I manually reinstalled Armadillo in /home/me/armadillo-4.650.3, following option 1 as described here:

[C++ building error for a simple code using armadillo and hdf5 libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295725/c-building-error-for-a-simple-code-using-armadillo-and-hdf5-libraries)

However, even after reinstalling RcppArmadillo, it's still not possible save matrices in the HDF5 format. Can you help me make this possible?

Comment: Point two in the post you linked is your answer. Use it.  Closing this as a double.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel How can I set these compiler options when building my package?

Comment: Read "Writing R Extensions", look for Makevars file.