# c++ undefined reference to vtable

Tags: c++, g++

I'm learning C++. I'm trying to do an exercise where I define several implementations of a pure virtual class with a single function. I'm having trouble linking the class that uses these implementations.

```
==> BasicMath.h <==
#ifndef BASIC_MATH_H
#define BASIC_MATH_H

#include<string>
#include<vector>    

class BasicMath { };


#endif // BASIC_MATH_H

==> Operation.h <==

#ifndef OPERATION
#define OPERATION

#include<string>
#include<vector>    

class Operation {
 public:
  virtual void perform(std::vector<std::string> vec) = 0;
};


#endif // OPERATION

==> Sum.h <==
#ifndef SUM_H
#define SUM_H

#include "Operation.h"

class Sum: public Operation {
 public:
  void perform(std::vector<std::string> vec);
};

#endif // SUM_H

==> BasicMath.cpp <==
#ifndef BASIC_MATH_C
#define BASIC_MATH_C

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "BasicMath.h"
#include "Sum.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Sum op;
}

#endif // BASIC_MATH_C

==> Sum.cpp <==
#ifndef SUM_C
#define SUM_C

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Sum.h"

void Sum::perform(std::vector<std::string> vec) {
    using namespace std;
    int total = 0;
    cout << "Total: " << total << "\n";
};

#endif // SUM_C
```

Compilation:

```
$ g++ -c Sum.cpp
$ g++ -o BasicMath BasicMath.cpp
/tmp/cc1VXjNl.o:BasicMath.cpp:(.text$_ZN3SumC1Ev[Sum::Sum()]+0x16): undefined reference to `vtable for Sum'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm 95% sure I'm doing at least one foolish thing here - but my brain is refusing to tell me what.

I have see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-referen/3430534#3430534) question but have not managed to fix my issue.

Comment: Side note: You definitely want to pass an std::vector by reference, not by value.

Comment: Side note 2: Classes with virtual functions should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: I have added the g++ tag, as your problem is in how to get the compiler (more precisely linker) to link object files, and that is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not including the Sum.o object file on your compile&link line (second g++ use).

Comment: ok that was excruciatingly easy. Thanks Noah. Take the other points about pass by ref etc. I'll work on that next now I'm past this error. g++ manual goes on the reading list!

Comment: Correct, I was not compiling the `cpp` file of an included class.

Answer (score 31):

I Just encountered the same problem, but my problem was that I had not written the destructor code in my .cpp file.

class.h:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
};
```

class.cpp:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {}
```

It just gave me the vtable error message, and implementing the (empty) destructor solved the problem.

[Edit] Thus, the corrected class file looks like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {}
MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

Comment: Apparently, this can be common enough. +1 ... this helped me resolve the same issue.

Comment: The second code block isn't "implementing the (empty) destructor" as you say, that's implementing the constructor.

Comment: The second code block intentionally displayed the state which produced the error. I thought the sentence afterwards would be suffice for the solution but I added the "corrected" contents.

Answer (score 10):

**That error also happens if you forget the `= 0` for pure virtual functions**

Error:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void f();
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void f() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base *b = &d;
    (void)b;
}
```

No error:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

This is because without the `= 0`, C++ does not know that it is a pure virtual function, treats it as a declaration, expecting a later definition.

Tested on `g++` 5.2.1.

Tested as of GCC 11.2.0, the error message changed to:

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for Base'
```

command:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
```

Comment: guy you save my life XD

Answer (score 6):

A couple of people have already pointed out the solution to the problem you've seen.

I'll add something rather different. You only need header guards in your headers. You've included them in your *source files* as well, where they really *don't* make sense. For example, I've commented out the lines you really don't need (or even want) in sum.cpp:

```
//#ifndef SUM_C
//#define SUM_C
//
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Sum.h"

void Sum::perform(std::vector<std::string> vec) {
    using namespace std;
    int total = 0;
    cout << "Total: " << total << "\n";
};

//#endif // SUM_C
```

Just FWIW, instead of `perform`, I'd use `operator()`:

```
class Operation {
 public:
  virtual void operator()(std::vector<std::string> vec) = 0;
};
```

and (obviously) that's also what you'd overload for `Sum`. To use it, instead of something like:

```
Sum op;
op.perform();
```

You'd use something like:

```
Sum op;
op();
```

This is particularly convenient when you combine your class with others (e.g., those in the standard library) that invoke operations like functions, whether they're really functions, or "functors" (classes like this, that overload `operator()` so syntactically they can be used almost like functions).

Comment: Hi Jerry - I added the guards in my source after reviewing some of the ACE code, which had this style http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html. Perhaps this is required for some frameworks or is just now defunct?

Answer (score 2):

I normally encounter this error when I accidentally forget the `=0` at the end of one of my functions in a pure virtual class.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. =0 means that your class will be abstract. I guess the problem is that you forgot to write a function body.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me.

Comment: @EboMike The body is not required when you use `... = 0`. So it would solve some of the issues (not for a destructor, though).

Comment: Why that works: the `= 0` ensures the compiler/linker doesn't try to find that member function definition (implementation) *for that virtual class* -- which doesn't exist when you want that member function to be virtual ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have met the problem same as yours , and I solved this problem by adding three lines in the **CMakeLists.txt** , that is:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

Comment: Hi, please keep in mind that, as the cmake manual shows, these are very specific to cmake and QT projects ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I were so troubled without knowing my problem also with MOC. for some reason my header file wasn't targeted by `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` so I had to use `#include "moc_<header_base>.cpp"` **instead of** `#include "<header_base>.h"`. hope it helps if someone face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're just compiling BasicMath.cpp without Sum.cpp - your linker has no idea about Sum.cpp. You'll need to compile them both together, i.e. `Sum.cpp BasicMath.cpp` in one go, or you can compile the .cpp files independently and then create the executable by calling g++ with both .o files.