# Why does my C++ compiler say that a virtual member has no definition?

Tags: c++, g++

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272432/c-undefined-reference-to-vtable) is possibly a duplicate, but I am not sure because my program is in a single file.

```
// my-program.cpp

class A
{
public:
  virtual void foo();
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
  B myB;
}
```

Then I type `g++ my-program.cpp` into the terminal, and the compiler gives me this warning:

*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"typeinfo for A", referenced from:
typeinfo for Bin cce8BmNY.o
"vtable for A", referenced from:
A::A()     in cce8BmNY.o
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says there is no definition because there is no definition. You've declared `A::foo()`, but not defined it.

Perhaps you want it to be pure virtual (making the base class `A` abstract):

```
virtual void foo() = 0;
```

In this case, it doesn't need a definition, since it will always be overridden in any class that can be instantiated.

Or perhaps you want to be able to instantiate `A` directly, in which case it will need a definition.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a function with no definition you should write `virtual void foo() = 0;`.