# g++ compile multiple files

Tags: g++

I'got a problem with <strike>compiling</strike> linking of a program with multiple files by g++ (I usually use vstudio, but...).

1. If I use only main.cpp (and include appropriate header files for openCV), everything is ok with

   ```
   g++ main.cpp -o main  -I"C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv" -L"C:\OpenCV2.1\lib" 
   -lcxcore210 -lcv210 -lhighgui210
   ```
2. If I have main.cpp and some otherfile.cpp (both need openCV) and use

   ```
   g++ main.cpp otherfile.cpp -o main  -I"C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv" 
   -L"C:\OpenCV2.1\lib" -lcxcore210 -lcv210 -lhighgui210
   ```

   it simply doesn't work and I got

   ```
   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: a
   uto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the c
   ommand line.
   This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols
    from auto-imported DLLs.
   C:\Users\ONDEJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNisCoC.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16d0): undefin
   ed reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool)'
   C:\Users\ONDEJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNisCoC.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16f1): undefin
   ed reference to `cv::FAST(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocat
   or<cv::KeyPoint> >&, int, bool)'
   C:\Users\ONDEJM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNisCoC.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7relea
   seEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x3f): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a linking problem rather than a compilation problem. Have you tried compiling main.cpp and otherfile.cpp separately then linking the resulting .o files together? Does this affect the error at all?

Comment: yes, I tried. Compiling of both files separately is not a problem, however, building them together returns the same error

Comment: See the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-referen/1095321#1095321 for more info on this

Comment: tried to change the order of -l, however didn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it seems that I made a silly mistake... solution is simple: just recompile all openCV binarries by g++ and everything will be ok!

Answer (score 0):

Pass "-Wl,--enable-auto-import" to g++. Read ld's documentation about this.