# Flex compiling error

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to describe grammar for toy language. Here is the contents of `tokens.lex`:

```
/* Simple scanner for a toy language */

%{
/* need this for the call to atof() below */
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
%}

IDENTIFIER [a-z][a-z0-9]*
DIGIT      [0-9]

%%
{DIGIT}+ {
  printf("int: %s (%d)\n", yytext, atoi(yytext));
  yylval.string = new std::string(yytext, yyleng);
} /* define int type */

{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}+ {
  printf("float: %s (%d)\n", yytext, atof(yytext));
  yylval.string = new std::string(yytext, yyleng);
} /* define float type */

b[\'\"]{IDENTIFIER}[\'\"] {
  printf("bstream: %s\n", yytext);
  yylval.string = new std::string(yytext, yyleng);
} /* define bstream type */

u[\'\"]{IDENTIFIER}[\'\"] {
  printf("ustream: %s\n", yytext);
  yylval.string = new std::string(yytext, yyleng);
} /* define ustream type */

if|then|begin|end|procedure|function {
  printf( "A keyword: %s\n", yytext );
}

{IDENTIFIER}      printf( "identifier: %s\n", yytext );

"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"   printf( "operator: %s\n", yytext );

"{"[^}\n]*"}"     /* Remove one-line comments */

[ \t\n]+          /* Remove whitespace */

.                 printf( "Unrecognized character: %s\n", yytext );

%%
int argc;
char **argv;
int main(argc, argv);
  {
  if ( argc > 0 )
    yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
  else
    yyin = stdin;
  yylex();
  }
```

Then I try to compile it:

`lex tokens.lex && g++ -lfl lex.yy.c`

Compiler returns a couple of errors:

```
tokens.lex:51:20: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
tokens.lex:51:20: error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
tokens.lex:52:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

What can be wrong here? I'm not very strong in C/C++, so I can't find out what happens here. Could you help me, please? THanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell flex(1) to generate C++? `flex -+ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write the main function is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc > 1)
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  else
    yyin = stdin;
  return yylex();
}
```

1. The type of an argument should be placed before the argument name
2. The element [0] of the argv array is the program name itself. The real arguments start at [1].

Comment: g++ tells:

/tmp/ccLObecG.o: In function `main':
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x1e32): multiple definition of `main'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../lib64/libfl.a(libfl_a-libmain.o):/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/flex-2.5.35/libmain.c:29: first defined here
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../lib64/libfl.a(libfl_a-libmain.o): In function `main':
libmain.c:(.text.startup+0xb): undefined reference to `yylex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @ghostmansd: The order is important when linking. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-refere/1095321#1095321 for an explanation (here you require "yylex" and it is provided in "libfl").

Comment: Actually, there's one thing you didn't notice. There was a semicolon before the block. That's what the compiler was complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Your main() argument declarations are incorrect 'C' syntax as noted in another answer, but this is all wrong anyway. Your lexer has to *return* tokens, not just print them. The main() function for lex/flex must call yylex() until it returns zero or -1 or whatever the EOS indication is. That's what the one in the lex library does.