# Vector with multiple class objects yields a compilation error?

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, declaration

For the following class I wanted to make a vector with 10 Ship() objects

However this yields the following compilation error **invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]**

( If I omit the vector line it compiles just fine)

 *I did a little search and could not find an answer.*

```
class Ship
{

protected:
        std::string name;
public:
        Ship(std::string name="Ship")
        {
          std::ostringstream tmp;
          std::string temp;
          tmp << name << ++id;
          name = tmp.str();
        }
};
```

Vector Declaration in main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Ship.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
int main()
{
     vector<Ship> Shipyard; //10% of map dimension is number of ships
     Shipyard.push_back(Ship(10)); //push_back(Ship(),10); doesn't work also
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor takes a `std::string`, but you're passing an integer

For 10 objects construction of *same name* use this *2nd form* of [constructor of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) :

```
vector<Ship> Shipyard( 10, Ship() );
```

Comment: vector<Ship> Shipyard; 
Shipyard.push_back(10,Ship());
is identical? (because this one yields error)

Comment: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Ship>::push_back(int, Ship)'

Comment: @niCk Did you read the my entire post correctly, I didn't use `push_back`. You just have to use the appropriate constructor

Comment: This line of code vector<Ship> Shipyard( 10, Ship() );
yields this error:Undefined reference to 'vtable for Ship'

Comment: I read your entire post I just asked for push_back identical syntax but its ok leave it, I deleted the push_back line

Comment: @nick Now, this current error is unrelated to your current question, you need to provide more details. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1095298/1870232) post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65003/discussion-between-nick-and-p0w).

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a `Ship` object with the value of `10`.  Since the constructor takes `std::string`, you cannot pass an integer to the constructor.

To add 10 ships:

```
std::vector<Ship> ShipYard(10);
```

or

```
std::vector<Ship> ShipYard;
ShipYard.resize(10);
```

Comment: thanks however I can't find nowhere how to add 10 objects of Ship() constructor in one line (not manually)

Comment: Please see the updated answer.  You are looking for `resize()`, not `push_back`.

Comment: I added resize() however how to call Ship() for every vector element (I suppose that after resize it has nothing right?)

Comment: The `resize` will default construct 10 Ship objects.

Comment: it yields this compiler error undefined reference to `vtable for Ship' (and shows me the Ship constructor line)

Comment: @niCk - You are not posting your entire code.  The code at the link compiles with no errors:  http://ideone.com/viuFeK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65004/discussion-between-nick-and-paulmckenzie).

Comment: I have 2 virtual methods Should I edit?
Their bodies are defined separately in subclasses

Answer (score 1):

```
Ship(10)
```

This will try to create one Ship object and call the constructor. However your constructor take `string` as argument and hence the error.

To create vector of 10 `Ship`s use:

```
vector<Ship> Shipyard(10, Ship());
```