# Why does the compiler throw "undefined reference to ..." despite providing all needed libraries in the arguments

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, linker-errors, psapi

I'm working on a program that will monitor the usage of chosen programs and will log it into a .csv file. That way, I can determine what programs use up the most of a certain resource while I run a game in full-screen. I have included the psapi header like so:

```cpp
...
#include <psapi.h>
...
```

And I compile with MinGW's G++ with the following options and necessary libraries for the function I'm using (libraries were from the documentation of the function): `g++ -lkernel32 -lpsapi test.cpp -o test.exe`

Yet it still throws the error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\cclpYDm2.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x3e7): undefined reference to `GetProcessMemoryInfo@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I feel that either something is wrong with my library or there's something I'm doing wrong. I've tried surrounding the header with "extern "C"" and I still get the same exact message. I have also verified that the library exists; if it did not, the compiler would have thrown a different error. `#pragma comment` does not work either, and using the `-static` flag has no effect. I have also tried defining the PSAPI_VERSION macro and setting it to 1, placing it before the include statement of psapi.

TL;DR: Compiler is throwing an undefined reference error despite having correct libraries. I suspect it's either:

- Library was installed incorrectly
- I'm doing something wrong on linking

Comment: To whoever marked this as a duplicate, could you please tell me what answer this relates to? Thanks.

Comment: Try linking against `kernel32.lib`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it still threw the same error, with and without psapi's library included.

Comment: @Jamesthe1 Well, it seems you miss to link the library which contains the implementation for `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` (I guess that's part of the Windows SDK). It's very clear that it was me marking that as a duplicate BTW.

Comment: Upon re-reading the documentation, I **do** have the proper libraries linked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo#requirements

Comment: So, is this a me issue, a linker issue, or a library issue?

Comment: A minimal, complete example that could replicate the problem would have been helpful. It's hard to know if you ever got everything right at the same time. For example, where did you put the `#define PSAPI_VERSION 1`? Maybe it's in the wrong place.

Comment: The macro was defined before any include. I understand that 'function@num' usually means it has something to do with a library (if it were an incorrectly-declared function, it would print out 'function(arg)' instead)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you please re-open this question? No solution exists within the highly-general post you linked to, and I have described how it is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this instead. The sequence of arguments you provided to g++ actually matters. Always put the library at the end of your arguments.

```
g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -lkernel32 -lpsapi
```

The g++ tool chain will first go through `test.cpp` and compile it to a binary object file, which is a temporary file having a funny name, but let us call it `test.o` for now. At this time, there are still some function references in `test.o` which cannot be resolved.

Then, the g++ tool chain sees `-lkernel32` and then `-lpsapi`. It goes in these two libraries in sequence and find those missing functions in `test.o` for you.

If you are linking statically, it will copy the compiled binary code of the functions in need from the library and splice it to `test.o`. If you are linking dynamically, it will set up some "entry" to the dynamic library.

This is what makes the sequence to be important. The compiler tool chain will *only* copy (set up entry) those function *in need*, since a library is typically very large and contains many other functions you don't really need. When currently nothing is needed from the libraries, like the command you originally wrote, g++ needs nothing from `-lkernel32 -lpsapi` before running into `test.cpp`, it will simply skip those libraries.

In short, if `lib_a` depends on `lib_b`, you should put `lib_a` before `lib_b` in the arguments. In rare cases where `lib_x` depends on `lib_y` which in turn depends on `lib_x`, you must write something like `g++ file.cpp lib_x lib_y lib_x`.

Note that this rule only applies to libraries. *All* functions in the source file will be kept in the binary object file. Thus, even if `file_x` depends on `file_y`, writing `g++ file_y.cpp file_x.cpp` is okay, since all functions are kept in `file_y.o` and `file_x.o`, when linking them together, the linker can find them.

Related question: [GCC C++ Linker errors: Undefined reference to 'vtable for XXX', Undefined reference to 'ClassName::ClassName()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-refere?rq=1)

Comment: @M.M It's a good point. Only libraries matter. Let me elaborate more on the answer.