# Point Cloud Library, linking libraries with g++

Tags: c++, g++, point-cloud-library

I want to run [sample code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php) from PCL site to simple read cloud from file.
I installed libraries, and prepared build script:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lboost_system `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4` -g -o main
```

but compiller throws many errors like:

```
/usr/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:56: undefined reference to `vtable for pcl::PCDReader'
```

I know that I need to linking *libpcl_io.so* like I linked *boost library* by adding *-lboost_system* , but my question is - how?
I tried add to script something like *-lpcl*, *-libpcl*, *-lpcl_io*, but it doesn't works

So, what is keyword to linking PCL Libraries?

Comment: Are you making use of CMake and Make?

Comment: No, just save this script as .sh, make it executable and run, when I want to build my program. I always did it this way

Comment: Is this of any help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-refere

Comment: Do you have any good reason not to use CMake? Exactly because of this reason, CMake is being used, so you don't have to worry about all of the `g++` shenanigans.

Comment: How did you install PCL?